# How to populate Content Provider without a DB

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contentprovider

In my Android application, I'm using an Intent-based third party library application.
The 3rd party lib requires a Content Provider containing the data generated from my app.

Unfortunately, my app doesn't use db or any kind of persistence: data is totally volatile.
As a consequence, the Content Provider has no db to fetch data from.

Ideally I'd like to pass data to the Content Provider when the Android runtime instanciates it. Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks regards
Vincenzo

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a `MatrixCursor`. It is a **mutable** cursor and you can add rows at runtime. Pass this cursor to your ContentProvider and it would like a normal db cursor. You can search google for examples.

Comment: Hi Akhil thanks for your reply. I know this api but what is not clear to me is when should I do this. What I mean is that I have no control on when the content provider is instanciated by the runtime. How can I populate the CP before the library uses it?

Comment: You can do this at the cp's instantation method itself i.e.  in onCreate() lifecycle.

Comment: Ok but the data I need exists as volatile variables within the main Activity of the application. How can I fetch this data from within the onCreate method of the Content Provider?

Comment: Make a class which stores the variables from activity and cp will ask using a get().. method of the class. Since cp also starts in same process it should be able to access the object